# Three.js Object appears Hollow after Clipping?

Tags: javascript, three.js, clipping

I am trying to clip off portions of a box in three.js , but each time the box crosses the ClipPath it's insides appear hollow.

[image: As seen below (box is brown)]

Is there a way to render the box so it looks solid after it is clipped?

Or is there an easier way to clip the ends of the box that stick outside the bounds of this triangle?

[image: Box sticking out of Triangle]

I'm still learning so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090942/how-to-render-clipped-surfaces-as-solid-objects

Comment: Also see http://daign.github.io/clipping-with-caps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to insert a triangle yourself to make the new face resulting from the corner being cut off.

It's a simple example of a powerful general technique called [Constructive Solid Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry).

Comment: I think I see what your saying, but I'm not sure how you implement it in three.js . I've tried working with Intersection Clipping [like here in the examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=plane#webgl_clipping_intersection) but unfortunately I still get a hollow effect.

Comment: @Nolakat have a look at http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/

Comment: Ah this is really useful. Thanks!!