# pythreejs: How to render clipped surfaces as solid objects

Tags: three.js, pythreejs

I'd like to achieve what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093210 with `pythreejs` in JupyterLab instead of pure javascript.

Can I somehow subclass MeshPhongMaterial in python to add this change?

I am also happy to go the `ShaderMaterial` route (see https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/blob/master/examples/Shaders.ipynb) , if I would understand how to use `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` so that is roughly looks like `MeshStandarMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial` (I need ambient and point lights and `DoubleSide` light support).

Of course, any other idea that gets me to what is depicted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093210 with `pythreejs` is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It was surprisingly easy to port the `SectionHelper` mentioned in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186639

```
class SectionHelper(Mesh):
    def __init__(self, object, hexOrMaterial):
        if isinstance(hexOrMaterial, MeshBasicMaterial):
            material = hexOrMaterial
        else:
            color = hexOrMaterial
            material = MeshBasicMaterial(color=color, side="BackSide")

        super().__init__(object.geometry, material)

        self.matrix = object.matrixWorld
        self.matrixAutoUpdate = False
```

The result is then as expected

```
from ipywidgets import Layout
material = MeshPhongMaterial(color = "green", side="DoubleSide", diffuse="red")

torus = Mesh(
    TorusKnotBufferGeometry(radius=20, tube=5, tubularSegments=64, radialSegments=64, p=2, q=3), 
    material=material
)

sec = SectionHelper(torus, "#ff00ff")

key_light = DirectionalLight(color='white', position=[3, 5, 1], intensity=0.5)

c = PerspectiveCamera(position=[0, 100, 100], up=[0, 1, 0], children=[key_light])

scene = Scene(children=[torus, sec, c, AmbientLight(color='#777777')], background=None)

renderer = Renderer(camera=c, 
                    scene=scene,
                    alpha=True,
                    clearOpacity=0,
                    controls=[OrbitControls(controlling=c)],
                    width=500, height=500)

renderer.localClippingEnabled = True;
display(renderer)

for i in range(-64, 64):
    renderer.clippingPlanes = [Plane((0,-1,0), i/2.0)]
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

[clipped torusknot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2IHm.png)